# Load JQuery script if screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I'm using [this](http://www.masterslider.com/jquery/) image carousel on a website that I'm building.

If the screen size is greater than 768px, I would like it to run:

```
var slider = new MasterSlider();
slider.setup('masterslider' , {
     width:1440,    // slider standard width
     height:400,   // slider standard height
     space:5,
     layout:'boxed',

});
// adds Arrows navigation control to the slider.
slider.control('arrows');
```

If the screen size is less than 768px, I would like it to kill the previous script and run.

```
var slider = new MasterSlider();
slider.setup('masterslider' , {
     width:1440,    // slider standard width
     height:400,   // slider standard height
     space:5,
     layout:'autofill',

});
// adds Arrows navigation control to the slider.
slider.control('arrows');
```

I've tried achieving this with Modernizr mq, but the trigger doesn't appear to work:

```
if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 767px)')) {
    // Script option 1
} else {
    // Script option 2
}
```

I would like to do this on the resize of the viewport and avoid refreshing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the behavior on re-size event.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", updateLayout, false); 

function updateLayout() {
  if(window.innerWidth > 767) {
    // modify to layout one
  } else {
    // modify to other layout
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the layout property via a ternary operator so you wont need to specify two separate init functions.

```
var slider = new MasterSlider();
slider.setup('masterslider' , {
    width: 1440,    // slider standard width
    height: 400,   // slider standard height
    space: 5,
    layout: $(document).width() > 768 ? 'boxed' : 'autofill'
});
// adds Arrows navigation control to the slider.
slider.control('arrows');
```

Comment: This is a very clean solution, but the layout change doesn't appear to be triggering. Is there a way via dev tools I can see the change? Then I can determine if it's a CSS issue I'm having.

Comment: It looks like it's working if I refresh the page. Is there a way to trigger this without a refresh?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear you were trying to do this on resize. You'll need to re-set the layout property. You should be able to do this by invoking slider.setup with an object containing only the layout value. You should probably do this on the end of the resize event rather than during the entire event. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/done-resizing-event/ for how to do that.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you. I've added a line to my question about the re-size so you can update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
function check_device(){
    if($(window).width() > 768){
        var slider = new MasterSlider();
        slider.setup('masterslider' , {
           width:1440,    // slider standard width
           height:400,   // slider standard height
           space:5,
           layout:'boxed',

         });
         // adds Arrows navigation control to the slider.
         slider.control('arrows');
     }else{
         var slider = new MasterSlider();
         slider.setup('masterslider' , {
            width:1440,    // slider standard width
            height:400,   // slider standard height
            space:5,
            layout:'autofill',

         });
         // adds Arrows navigation control to the slider.
         slider.control('arrows');
     } //END CHECK DEVICE SIZE
}//END check_device FUNCTION

$(window).resize(function(){
   check_device();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   check_device();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Vince.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I've tried this before, but it gives me the following console error multiple times: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

Comment: Mmm..strange you might have some error in your code because in the code i posted there is no property position.